# Действия в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть программа на wpf. Подключился к SQL-серверу, получаю данные и работаю. Но часто подключение или запрос выполняется не моментально, программа подвисает (или вообще вылетает, если вдруг нет сервера), хочу запускать действия в потоке, что б программа продолжала работать, а поток "брал" данные и добавлял их в программу.

Из всего инета нашёл рабочий пример только здесь: [использование потоков и BackgroundWorker в WPF](http://andsemenoff.narod.ru/programming/wpf/BackgroundWorker_page1.html). Но здесь немножко не то, что надо, и просто подставив этот код в мою прогу, ничего не заработало. Пишет

> Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь делать?

Answer (score 3):

WPF. В коде XAML определен Button с именем button. Там, где вылетает исключение, надо написать следующее

```
button.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
{
/// что-нибудь делаем
}));
```

Comment: А для чего button? (То есть, весь код оставить так же, как и в предыдущем примере, а это вставить в той строке, где выдаёт ошибку?)

Answer (score 0):

Когда такая ошибка возникает, это значит, что нужно использовать Dispatcher для того, чтобы получить корректный доступ к объекту. См. внизу статьи вторую «ссылку по теме».

Comment: Я посмотрел.
А есть, где наглядный пример? а то я не оч шарю((((((((